# Late 2013 Macbook Pro takes full days to charge ; battery drops when unplugging charger?

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

My Macbook pro has to charge overnight to get an even usable charge (usually 50%), and when I unplug the charger from it drops to around 1-6%. I just replaced the battery and coconut app says its fine, charging with enough watts, etc. Have no idea what is going on.

[image]

Edit: should note, it only charges when off. When its on it claims its not charging. Unplugging the charger while its on causes it to drop or completely turn off.

Comment: Bring it back to wherever you bought it and have it checked (you should still have warranty).

Comment: Have you try a Reset SMC : https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/if-your-battery-wont-charge-mh29198/mac ?

Comment: I’ve tried the SMC Reset but it doesn’t help.

Comment: Welcome to **Ask Different** -- RE: "I just replaced the battery" --  Did _you_ replace the battery or did you take it to a service center? If the later, take it back. Otherwise take it to have it serviced, as I seriously doubt there is anything that someone here can do for you.

Comment: I replaced the battery myself, and it claims the battery is fine but is there any way the charger ports could have a problem? Or something internally that needs to be cleaned?

Comment: Have you experienced the same issue before replacing the battery?

Comment: Yes, but when I got it serviced at an apple store (the computer did say the battery needed to be serviced), they only said it was a problem with the battery. So I replaced it myself, and now while it does charge a little quicker and lives a little longer, its still mostly the same + this new problem of the battery dropping sporadically and dying at 6%. Then takes a day+ to charge. :/

Answer (score 2):

Logically, there are three possibilities:

a) the charger is faulty
b) the power management unit is faulty
c) the battery is faulty

The charger is the easiest to test: see if you can find another Magsafe 2 charger.

Realistically, the other two need to be tested by an Apple Store or other authorised/qualified technician.

Apple don't sell replacement parts to the public, so any battery you bought will be a third-party attempt to match the specification (within costs). Printed text saying "Designed by Apple" etc is unlikely to be a guarantee of anything.